# Cheap Git GUI for on premise use

Tags: git

Looking for a Git GUI that

- supports on premise servers like GitLab (not only Cloud)
- does not cost more than 5$ a month
- is easy to use for beginners
- runs on Windows 10

Answer (score 4):

Instead of providing an own UI [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) uses Windows Explorer and extends context menu e.g. of folders that belong to Git repositories.

For [common git operations](https://tortoisegit.org/about/screenshots/) like commit, push, pull... it provides own UI dialogs.

It also has a dialog for synchronizing local repository branches with remote repository branches.

[TortoiseGit is an open source project](https://github.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/) (GPLv2)

Answer (score 2):

Could try [Atlassian Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)

I've only used it with cloud services, but it looks as though it [can be made to work with GitLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570370/how-to-integrate-sourcetree-for-gitlab) and I'm guessing that applies to local servers as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

- [Glint](https://glint.info) (Nice UI with good feature set, mac/windows/linux, $4/month)
- [Fork](https://git-fork.com/) (Good feature set, mac/windows, $50/lifetime)
- [Git Kraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) (Advanced features, mac/windows/linux $5/month)
- [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) (Nice UI but only simple features, mac/windows, free)

Disclaimer: I am the creator of Glint.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try the [Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) app? I think it is free.

I know it is for GitHub, but it can be made to work with Gitlab. At least, according to  a few instructions such as this [one](https://itnext.io/how-to-use-github-desktop-with-gitlab-cd4d2de3d104) (from 2018) or [this one](https://www.devopszones.com/2020/08/how-to-use-github-desktop-with-gitlab.html) (from 2020).

Users still need a GitHub account though.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Git Extensions]

It appears to have all the features.

- Integrates with File Explorer
- View Commit Log
- View File History
- You can use your own editor and/or diff program.  I use Beyond Compare with it.

And I am not affiliated with it.

Screenshot of one of my repos
[image: screenshot]

Screenshot of one of the setup pages

[image: Setup]